# Intersection of Power set and Power set of power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\mathscr P(S)$ denotes power set of a set $S$ then is $\mathscr P(S) \cap \mathscr P(\mathscr P(S)) = \{\emptyset\}$?

My book says its true.

I considered a simple set $S=\{1,2\}$

Now $\mathscr P(S) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$
$$
\mathscr P(\mathscr P(S))= \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}, \{\{1\}\}, \{\{2\}\},\{\{1,2\}\}, \{\{1\}\,\{2\}\}, \{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}, \{\{2\},\{1,2\}\} , \ldots\}
$$
Now $\mathscr P(S) \cap \mathscr P(\mathscr P(S))=\emptyset$ and not $\{\emptyset\}$.

So I think that above claim is wrong.

---

If I go by theorem of power set intersection which says $\mathscr P(A) \cap \mathscr P(B)=\mathscr P(A\cap B)$ and put $A=\mathscr P(S)$ and $B=\mathscr P(S)$, then I get
$$
\mathscr P(S) \cap \mathscr P(\mathscr P(S)) = \mathscr P(S \cap \mathscr P(S)) = \mathscr P(\emptyset)={\emptyset}. 
$$
So if I go by theorem, then the claim seems to be correct.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: In your example, $P(S)$ has four elements so $P(P(S))$ should have $16$ and the last element has a repeated element within it, but that does not change the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to consider pairing the elements with $\phi$

Comment: @Arthur, Yes, that is possible. Maybe the book didn't consider such cases. You can check the answer by user503979 below. He describes the same thing.

Comment: $P(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$, $P(\emptyset) \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first argument, you're claiming that $P(S)$ and $P(P(S))$ have empty intersection, but they have one element in common, namely $\emptyset$, so their intersection is $\{\emptyset\}$, as claimed.

Comment: How is $\emptyset$ same as $\{\emptyset\}$ ?

Comment: It's not. We have $\emptyset$ *in* the intersection, but $\{\emptyset\}$ *is* the intersection. This works, because $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: If $S=\{a,b,c\}$ and $T=\{a,e,i,o,u\}$, then $a\in S\cap T$, and $\{a\}=S\cap T$. Your example is basically the same, but we have $\emptyset$ for $a$.

Comment: Wew. Now I realize how stupid my question was :P. That $\phi$ just confused me.

Comment: That’s fair. It’s legitimately confusing!

Answer (score 11):

If $S=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, then $P(S) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and $P(P(S))$ will contain the *whole* of $P(S)$ as a subset.

So the statement as such does not generally follow.  Basically whenever a set contains an element as well as a set containing only that element, its powerset will contain the set containing that element as well (obviously).

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\emptyset \in P(S)$ and $\emptyset \in P(P(S))$ so $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq P(S) \cap P(P(S))$

Comment: Should that last "$\in$" be a "$\subset$"?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs:  yes, the horizontal line crept upwards a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *necessary* and *sufficient* condition for this to hold:

$$S \cap P(S) = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow P(S) \cap P(P(S)) = \{\emptyset\}\;.$$

Clearly, any powerset contains $\emptyset$ as element.  All *other* elements of $P(S)$ are non-empty subsets of $S$, all *other* elements of $P(P(S))$ are non-empty subsets of $P(S)$.  Any common element among those must thus be made from shared elements between $S$ and $P(S)$, and if there is a shared element $x$ between $S$ and $P(S)$, $\{x\}$ is a shared element between $P(S)$ and  $P(P(S))$.

An easy way to satisfy this is to have no sets as elements of $S$ since $P(S)$ has only sets as elements.